# How to assign multiple hotkeys to the same action?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vlc-media-player, autohotkey, hotkeys, key-binding

Here're my current hotkeys:

| Action | Hotkey |
| --- | --- |
| Short backward jump(10s) | J |
| Play / Pause | K |
| Short forward jump(10s) | L |

Given this config, I'm losing <kbd>Space</kbd> for pausing/playing, so the question is, how to bind <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd> (multiple hotkeys) to "Play / Pause"(same action)?

Comment: i have this exact same question; exact same hotkeys and everything. I'm trying to get VLC to mimic the youtube keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my working AHK script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode Regex

#IfWinActive i)vlc ahk_exe vlc.exe
  Space::Send {k}
#IfWinActive
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a way to do this with VLC alone, however, you could use [autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) on Windows platforms to implement this functionality yourself.

A script like this might be useful to press the 'k' key whenever space is pressed but only when VLC is focused:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_exe vlc.exe

Space::send, {k}
  
#IfWinActive
```

Source: https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=35981#p437963

Answer (score 0):

Well, VLC in [recent versions](http://download.videolan.org/pub/videolan/vlc/3.0.19/) atleast, does provide a way to add atmost 2 keys for same function, without needing any other external tool like Autohotkey(nothing against it, it's a great tool, I use it in games remapping all the time.).

I suggest you take a careful look at your User VLCRC file(`%APPDATA%\vlc\vlcrc`), once you open it in any text editor like *Notepad++* or *SublimeText*. And notice that it does provide another key setting called `global-key-{function_name}` like `global-key-record` which is for mid-video-play recording.

So if you assign the `Z` key to say `global-key-record` and save the file, next time you open any movie or episode in VLC player then just with Z key you will be able to quickly start/stop recording the video. So, just add these 2 lines to the end of that `VLCRC` file:

```
key-record=r
global-key-record=z
```

***Word of caution:*** Just be careful that if you intend to use any Global keys for functions in VLC, keep only VLC window in focus while you're using those keys. Because if you have accidentally any other window, let's say Firefox browser or VSCode editor or any other software in focus and VLC also running as minimized and if you press Z key then the VLC will start recoding the video, as in this sense *Global means Global*, so just make sure to keep focus on VLC window only and close the window or exit the VLC app altogether when you don't need to use any of it's globally-bound keys.

So now you can Record videos with 2 separate keys 1) R & 2) Z.